# Can not find Biztalk Buisiness Rule Engine registry directory on the biztalk server?

Tags: .net, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I am trying to update a StaticSupport key (for Invoking Static Members of a Class) for business rule engine in the windows registry , MSDN ([Invoking Static Members of a Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa950269.aspx#)) states that , it exists on path in registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\BusinessRules\3.0` but I do not find a BusinessRules sub-directory although I have installed the business rule engine on the server.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Just to be sure: have you also configured BRE on your BizTalk Server environment?

Comment: @PieterVandenheede sure , I configure it and I can deploy and create new rules but registry does not appear in registry path ,

Comment: Obvious question maybe, but you are looking on your BizTalk Server right (not on SQL) ? What version are you running?

Comment: yes sure , I am using BizTalk 2013 R2 , I installed the same version on another machine and I am getting all things fine @PieterVandenheede

Comment: Have you tried copying that registry key to the other machine?

Comment: Thanks @PieterVandenheede I realized that in 64 bit machine the path is deferent as answered below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 64-bit computers, the reg path is:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\**Wow6432Node**\Microsoft\BusinessRules\3.0

This is further down in the article.